# How do you rename a title in Filmora?

Tags: video-editor

I have added several Titles to my Filmora project. I am doing some basic motion tracking to multiple elements on my timeline. When I want to link one of the titles to a motion tracked object, it gives me a list of elements/titles to attach.

[image]

When I look closer at my titles in the timeline I can see their names in the tooltip

[image]

How do I edit these names? "Basic 6" isn't helpful or descriptive. I have no idea which title I'm linking to the motion tracking without trial/error.

I don't see anything in the interface for renaming titles but it's possible I'm just missing it.